# How to access an element's object on a halo event handler?

Tags: jquery, events, jointjs, rappid

When [customizing events for the Rappid Halo tool handles](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.2/ui.html#ui.Halo.events), the `arguments` variable seems to only have the `jQuery.Event` object and the x and y coordinates.

How can I get the cell/element or cellView in order to work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element's View can be found through `this.options.cellView`. Example for a removal handle:

```
{
  name: 'remove',
  position: 'ne',
  events: {
    pointerdown: function (evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      var elementView = this.options.cellView;

      // work on the element ...
      elementView.model.remove();
     }
  }
}
```

In this particular example, if the goal was to exclusively remove the element, then there is no need for a customized function, i.e.: `events: {pointerdown: 'removeElement'}`.